# Why is this react with redux code working?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**`App.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { action } from './Actions/actions'

class App extends Component {

  onClickHandle = (type) => {
    console.log(this.props.count)
    if (type === '+') {
      this.props.inc()
    }
    else {
      this.props.dec()
    }

  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>{this.props.count}</h1>
        <button onClick={() => this.onClickHandle('+')}>+</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.onClickHandle('-')}>-</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapDispatchToProps = a => {
  return {
    inc: () => a(action.increaseCount()),
    dec: () => a(action.decreaseCount()),
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    count: state.Counter.count
  }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

reducer.js

```
const initialState = {
count: 0
}
const counter = (state = initialState, action) => {
    console.log(action)
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return {
                count: state.count + 1
            };
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return {
                count: state.count - 1
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default counter;
```

action.js

```
    export const action = {
    increaseCount: count => (
        {
            type: 'INCREMENT',
            payload: count
        }),
    decreaseCount: count => (
        {
            type: 'DECREMENT',
            payload: count
        })
}
```

In this redux example I implemented an increment and decrement button and displaying the current count. I don't know why this is working, in `onClickHandle` I'm not passing current count to `inc()` or `dec()` so how these two functions knows what state I'm talking about, is store responsible for this? Please help I have already watched many tutorials but I can't understand.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not passing current count to inc() or dec()

You don't need this, your reducer knows what to do, when inc or dec sends it message with action type `INCREMENT` or `DECREMENT` and take current value from `state.count`. Because this currrent value doesnt belong to component state, it belongs to common store and reducer has an access to this store through `state` parameter

```
switch (action.type) {
        case 'INCREMENT':
            return {
                count: state.count + 1
            };
        case 'DECREMENT':
            return {
                count: state.count - 1
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
```

Comment: So, I don't have to pass state whenever I have to make changes in state. Like every time like in this case.

Comment: @AniketSaxena, no, because component itself got it from reducer

Comment: @DimitryReutov And can I say that every reducer holds some state. Not like literally but whenever I create a reducer redux automatically assign a state and map that state to that reducer. Can I say this?

Comment: @AniketSaxena, yes, there shoud be a code like: const rootReducer = combineReducers({ counter }), so the key is the name and value is reducer

Comment: @AniketSaxena, sorry, in your case code must be combineReducers({ Counter: counter })

Comment: In reducer I'm returning an object for every case, and at the time of returning reducers is also making updates in current state. Am I correct?